# Macbookpro 11.3 freeze entering in suspend mode with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, suspend, freeze, macbook-pro

I’ve installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Apple macbook pro 11,3 kernel 4.15.0-39 gnome version 3.28.2

My problem is connected with the suspend mode:

- when I try to put pc on suspend mode (pressing alt and clicking on the power icon on the top right panel of gnome interface) screen become black but the display light stay on. Pc freeze and I have to reset pressing power button. I tried call standby mode via command shell and the pc crash too.
- waiting suspend time screen became black but the  back-light remain on; in this case I can wake up the pc by the keyboard
- When I  close the lid o, the screen turns black  and after around 1 seconds the screen turns on again.

I tried:

- resetting smc
- changing linux kernel
- installing ubuntu 16.04 or 18.10
- using wayland
- echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup command

but unfortunately no one those  works...

Any suggestion?
Thanks for your help

Here my hardware list:

```
narkbkb@narkbkb-MacBookPro:~$ sudo lshw -short
```

And this the output:

```
[sudo] password di narkbkb: 
H/W path Device Class Description
================================================== ==========
system MacBookPro11,3 (System SKU#)
/0 bus Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663
/0/0 processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU
/0/0/2 memory 128KiB L1 cache
/0/0/3 memory 1MiB L2 cache
/0/0/4 memory 6MiB L3 cache
/0/1 memory 128KiB L1 cache
/0/6 memory 16GiB System Memory
/0/6/0 memory 8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 16
/0/6/1 memory 8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 16
/0/c memory 1MiB BIOS
/0/36dd memory 1019KiB BIOS
/0/100 bridge Crystal Well DRAM Controller
/0/100/1 bridge Crystal Well PCI Express x16 Co
/0/100/1/0 display GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edi
/0/100/1/0.1 multimedia GK107 HDMI Audio Controller
/0/100/1.1 bridge Crystal Well PCI Express x8 Con
/0/100/1.1/0 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/1.1/0/0 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/1.1/0/0/0 generic DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 NHI [Falc
/0/100/1.1/0/3 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/1.1/0/3/0 bridge DSL2210 Thunderbolt Controller 
/0/100/1.1/0/3/0/0 bridge DSL2210 Thunderbolt Controller 
/0/100/1.1/0/3/0/0/0 ens9 network NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethe
/0/100/1.1/0/4 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/1.1/0/5 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/1.1/0/6 bridge DSL5520 Thunderbolt 2 Bridge [F
/0/100/14 bus 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/14/0 usb1 bus xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1 bus Hub in Apple Extended USB Keybo
/0/100/14/0/1/1 input USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/0/1/2 printer Officejet Pro K550
/0/100/14/0/1/3 input Apple Extended USB Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/8 bus BRCM20702 Hub
/0/100/14/0/8/3 communication Bluetooth USB Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/c input Apple Internal Keyboard / Track
/0/100/14/1 usb2 bus xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/4 scsi0 storage Card Reader
/0/100/14/1/4/0.0.0 /dev/sdb disk SD Card Reader
/0/100/14/1/4/0.0.0/0 /dev/sdb disk 
/0/100/16 communication 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/1b multimedia 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Hi
/0/100/1c bridge 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/1c.2 bridge 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/1c.2/0 wlp3s0 network BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Netwo
/0/100/1c.3 bridge 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/1c.3/0 multimedia 720p FaceTime HD Camera
/0/100/1c.4 bridge 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/100/1c.4/0 storage Apple PCIe SSD
/0/100/1f bridge HM87 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.3 bus 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Fa
/0/2 scsi1 storage 
/0/2/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 500GB APPLE SSD SM0512
/0/2/0.0.0/1 volume 200MiB EFI GPT partition
/0/2/0.0.0/2 /dev/sda2 volume 381GiB Non-FS data partition
/0/2/0.0.0/3 /dev/sda3 volume 83GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2/0.0.0/4 /dev/sda4 volume 20MiB Linux swap volume
```